# Console.log not working within my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

So I'm trying to test my code out by applying a console.log in different parts of it. But when I try it in a certain function, it doesn't work. I've tried putting alerts within that function as well to see whether its just a problem with console.log, but alerts don't seem to run either.

Here's my code

```
var mqrule;
var lines;
var width;

console.log("Nothing");

//HASHMAP BEGINNING HERE
var newKey, newValue;
var MQHash = {};

MQHash[newKey] = newValue;

(function () {
    console.log("Nothing");
    //FROM HERE, CONSOLE.LOG DOESN'T SEEM TO BE WORKING.
    var mqEvents = function (mediaChangeHandler) {
        var sheets = document.styleSheets,
            numSheets = sheets.length,
            mqls = {},
            mediaChange = function (mql) {
                console.log(mql);
            }

        if (mediaChangeHandler) {
            mediaChange = mediaChangeHandler;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < numSheets; i += 1) {
            var rules = sheets[i].cssRules,
                numRules = rules.length;
            console.log("RULES: " + rules);

            for (var j = 0; j < numRules; j += 1) {
                if (rules[j].constructor === CSSMediaRule) {
                    mqrule = rules[j].cssText;
                    console.log(mqrule);
                    lines = (mqrule).split('\n');
                    console.log(lines[1]);
                    mqls['mql' + j] = window.matchMedia(rules[j].media.mediaText);
                    mqls['mql' + j].addListener(mediaChange);
                    mediaChange(mqls['mql' + j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //IT STARTS TO WORK AGAIN FROM HERE THOUGH.
    window.mqEvents = mqEvents;
}());

handleMediaChange = function (mql) {
    console.log();
    var medias = mql.media;
}
```

Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance. Sorry if this question isn't worded properly!

Comment: _alerts don't seem to run either_ clearly suggest problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Where are you calling mqEvents?

Comment: The alerts run outside of that section, but not within that section. Really sorry if this is silly, I'm fairly new to this!

Comment: If alerts and console.log aren't running, then clearly the code itself isn't running. Did you check if the value of `numSheets` is greater than 0?

Comment: @forgivenson yes you're right. But I'm not sure why! It was running fine yesterday. Logged back on today and now this!

Comment: Where/how is `mqEvents` being called?

Comment: How are you calling your `mqEvents` function? In your code you never call it, so you won't see any alert/console.log from that function.

Comment: @forgivenson yes the value of numSheets is greater than 0

Comment: @putvande You're right! I've now called it at the bottom with _mqEvents(handleMediaChange);_ and it's working fine! Thanks all!

Comment: You might be just defining the function, but not actually calling it. @Rafill

Answer (score 2):

OK I've figured it out thanks to you guys! I needed to call the function, which I so stupidly had forgotten to do, so I had added;

```
mqEvents(handleMediaChange);
```

at the bottom to call mqEvents.

Thanks all!